# Matrix centering and adding the number of the equation in the right

Tags: matrices

In fact, I am writing a paper and I am having a lot of equations with their respectives numbers.

So I want to center a matrix equation and write the number of the equation next to the matrix

Here is the latex code :

```
$
\begin{bmatrix}
V_\alpha \\
V_\beta  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
= $\frac{2}{3}$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{-1}{2}\\
0 & \frac{\sqrt3}{2} & \frac{-\sqrt3}{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
$
\begin{bmatrix}
V_a \\
V_b  \\
V_c  \\
\end{bmatrix}
$
```

Comment: remove all the `$` and put the equation in `\begin{equation}...`\end{equation}` and it will be set as a displayed equation and numbered.

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
V_\alpha \\
V_\beta  \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \frac{2}{3}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{-1}{2}\\
0 & \frac{\sqrt3}{2} & \frac{-\sqrt3}{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
V_a \\
V_b  \\
V_c  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks I had to add the usepackage{amssymb} to make this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to get simple numbered equations is to use the `equation` environment.

In addition to the `bmatrix` approach, I also give a `tabstackengine` approach, which gives more flexibility on conveniently setting the baselineskip of rows, which helps when fractions like this are set.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine,amsmath}
\setstackgap{L}{1.5\baselineskip}
\setstacktabbedgap{2ex}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
V_\alpha \\
V_\beta  \\
\end{bmatrix}
= \frac{2}{3}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{-1}{2}\\
0 & \frac{\sqrt3}{2} & \frac{-\sqrt3}{2} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
V_a \\
V_b  \\
V_c  \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\bracketMatrixstack{
V_\alpha \\
V_\beta
}
= \frac{2}{3}
\bracketMatrixstack{
1 & \frac{-1}{2} & \frac{-1}{2}\\
0 & \frac{\sqrt3}{2} & \frac{-\sqrt3}{2}
}
\bracketMatrixstack{
V_a \\
V_b  \\
V_c  
}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]